# cpanel and whm subdomains redirecting to cgi-sys/defaultwebpage.cgi

Tags: apache-2.2, domain-name-system

I have a new installation of WHM and cPanel and I'm adding domains into WHM, but when I try access via cpanel or whm subdomains, I got redirected to cgi-sys/defaultwebpage.cgi.

I've already tried into 3 different computers to check if is cache but the issue persists. I've checked the proxy domains but is enabled by default. What could be wrong?

Comment: Are the accounts linked to the correct IPs? Do the accounts show up in the apache configurations correctly?

Comment: @arjarj It was all right, seems to be a cPanel misconfiguration. Executing the commands below worked properly. Thanks.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about [`working with a service provider's management interface, such as cPanel`](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've contacted the cPanel Support and they told me to execute the following commands:

```
# /scripts/rebuildhttpdconf
# /scripts/restartsrv_httpd
```

After that, the subdomains worked properly.

Thanks everybody.

Comment: I get a permission denied. Did you have root access?

Comment: @Magpie Yes. All things related to server administration must be done by root.