# How can I block a redirect by my hosting provider to cgi-sys/defaultwebpage.cgi

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl

I run a couple of hosted domains in a shared hosting package with cpanel. I did not think it was worth paying for an ssl certificate so opted for a self signed certificate instead but the configuration is proving to be a nightmare and I cannot see where I am going wrong.

I adjusted my .htaccess in various ways based on some questions and answers I found on this site already, but no matter what I try the page defaults to `cgi-sys/defaultwebpage.cgi` for https and a 500 error for http (though earlier I had http working ok but I am trying to get that redirected to https automatically too)

Having read the apache documentation and [tried this](https://serverfault.com/questions/400364/cpanel-and-whm-subdomains-redirecting-to-cgi-sys-defaultwebpage-cgi?answertab=active#tab-top) which failed due to lack of permissions, I believe.

My htaccess in /home/magpie/public_html

```
 DocumentRoot /home/magpie/public_html
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    Options -ExecCGI -FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
    LoadModule ssl_module modules/mod_ssl.so
    SSLCertificateFile /home/magpie/ssl/certs/magpie.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /home/magpie/ssl/keys/magpie.key
    SSLEngine on
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
    DirectoryIndex index.php
</IfModule>
# block viewing any .httaccess files
<Files .htaccess>
    order allow, deny
    deny from all
</Files>
Order allow, deny
allow from all
```

I also made a default ssl.conf but was not sure where to put it. At the moment it is in ~/ssl and a path is set to the file in my ~/.bashrc

Update:

I have cleared the .htaccess file and as I said below, I have asked my hosting provider about their redirects and they said moving me to an updated server would help but now it just redirects to a site called purechimp.com. So far they are not being very forthcoming with a solution.

Update 2:

I was completely off track in thinking this problem was solvable with htaccess configuration but I learned a lot about the file so I am kind of glad I went through it anyway.

Instead I used my ssl.conf file and kept on at my hosting provider who came through in the end by removing the redirect which was taking my pages away from my site when using port 443. Unfortunately they did not tell me what they did and I am not sure whether any log I could access would be able to tell me either. I was rooting around in my cpan folders and found some configuration error saying i needed to install catalyst ssl when I found out so will have to come back to that issue and try and fix it later.

There's still a few configuration difficulties for my subdomains and other shared content I have in my hosting plan but I have the main site encrypted now and at the moment those sites are only html static pages so not too much to worry about.

I did try the startssl connection but the self signed certificate was already set up in my ssl.conf so I think that is what apache found when the hosting lot changed the setting. I am reluctant to change anything now it seems to be working well. If I can get my other domain set up to have ssl then I will be able to move those which I have hosted elsewhere in this same place which is great.

I did notice my favicon is the same as the favicon from the site I was redirected to... Not sure how to stop that happening since I don't know what my hoster changed. Any ideas would be appreciated, but I am selecting the answer below since it went some way to helping me solve the issues even if it was not a complete solution by itself.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. See if you can look at the Apache error log in cPanel.  That will be a huge help in figuring out why you're getting 500s.
2. However, I can see right now several things that will cause it.  None of the following directives are valid in .htaccess files:

   ```
   LoadModule 
   SSLCertificateFile
   SSLCertificateKeyFile
   SSLEngine
   ```

   The [Apache docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/directives.html) show that.  Any of those directives will cause 500s in a .htaccess file.  Since you can't set them there, you'll have to either use cPanel or talk to your hosting provider about what you need.
3. The redirect to `cgi-sys/defaultwebpage.cgi` is probably set somewhere in cPanel.  If you can't find the setting there, see if your hosting provider can help.
4. The self-signed certificate will only cause certificate errors, not any of the problems you described.  However, if you want a free certificate signed by a widely used CA, try [StartSSL](http://www.startssl.com).

Comment: Thanks the log file did help. I asked my hosting provider about their redirects and they said moving me to an updated server would help but now it just redirects to this site http://purechimp.com/. They are not being very forthcoming with a solution as I think they want me to pay them to install it but I don't see why I should pay to not have my sites redirected somewhere else!